# Navigation breadcrumb visibility for visitors

Tags: navigation, user, breadcrumb

I have a website which contains mostly normal webpages, which are stored in the Shared Documents section. The visitors are only able to read these pages. But when you see the breadcrumb in the above, you see "Startpage > Shared Documents > Page x", as a visitor.

When you click the second level link (Shared Documents) you're able to see the whole content of the website. Is their a way to edit this for the users?

Removing the breadcrumbs is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the below link and make adjustments as per your need:

[Hide Document library name like "Pages" link from BreadCrumb](http://kadyanmossnuts.blogspot.in/2008/08/hide-document-library-name-like-pages.html)

Comment: Works perfect, thanks! (Use 'documents partagés' when you're working with a French website).